# Regex for substring on NodeJS using pinch.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pinch.js

I am modifying JSON files/Javascript object using Pinch library: https://github.com/Baggz/Pinch

In this example, `pinch()` with regex parameter `/id/` modifies ALL the id values to `321`.

What I want to do is be able to change the value of all ids but only for a specific "Requestor", based on a parameter (`requestorToChange`). Let's say "RequestorX".  How do I write the regex for it?

```
var sample = {
  "RequestorX":
  [{
    user: {
      id: '123'
    },
    request: {
      id: '456'
    },
    book: {
      id: '789'
    }
  }],
  "RequestorY":
  [{
    user: {
      id: '111'
    },
    request: {
      id: '222'
    },
    book: {
      id: '333'
    }
  }]
};

const requestorToChange = 'RequestorX'

pinch(sample, /id/, function(path, key, value) {
  return '321';
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(sample))
```

I know that one option is to just do:

```
pinch(sample['RequestorX'], /id/, function(path, key, value) {
  return '321';
});
```

But I need to be able to do it via the regex field since in reality, I will be manipulating deeply nested JSON files.

Comment: Doesn't seem like "pinch" is the right tool for this. Just skimming through the docs, it doesn't look like searching by value is an option. You might have better luck with `jq` if you don't mind processing from the command-line (not sure if it has JS bindings), or you can just write a tiny algorithm to recursively walk through your object. Edit: Oh.. that isn't a value... but if you give a regex it'll only be applied against the leaf key, won't it?

Comment: BTW: The [tag:pinch] tag is almost exclusively used for pinch gestures. I've removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation on the GitHub page is a bit sparse, but basically you start with the dot notation replacement style and replace the variable parts with regex patterns whilst adhering to the rules of JS regular expressions.

So, in your case, a dot notation pattern `'RequestorX[0].user.id'`
becomes a regex like `/RequestorX\[0\]\.(user|request|book)\.id/`

Somes notes:

- first we have to escape the square brackets because those have special meaning in regex
- next, we also have to escape the . to use it as dot notation symbol
- we use a group with alternations to replace the id on all of them
- I tried to use `new RegExp` instead of the `/../` notation to create a regex Object to add your constant to the pattern, unfortunately only the first item is replaced in this case, probably a bug...

  ```
  pinch(sample, new RegExp(requestorToChange +'\[0\]\.(user|request|book)\.id'), '321');
  ```

Sample code (the SO code snippet outputs some extra gibberish about RequestorY, ignore it)

```js
var sample = {
  "RequestorX": [
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "123"
      },
      "request": {
        "id": "456"
      },
      "book": {
        "id": "789"
      }
    }
  ],
  "RequestorY": [
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "123"
      },
      "request": {
        "id": "456"
      },
      "book": {
        "id": "789"
      }
    }
  ]
}

const requestorToChange = 'RequestorX';
//var result = pinch(sample, 'RequestorX[0].user.id', '321'); //replace the user id of RequestorX with dot notation
var result = pinch(sample, /RequestorX\[0\]\.(user|request|book)\.id/, '321');
//var result = pinch(sample, new RegExp(requestorToChange +'\[0\]\.(user|request|book)\.id'), '321');
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pinch@0.1.3/src/pinch.js"></script>
```

Alas, JSON + regex sounds a bit weird but the tool looks legit.